# How to pair 2 list into 1 list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a code like this:

```
def datauji(self):
    uji = []
    for x in self.fiturs:
        a = [x[0],x[-5:]] #I think the problem in this line
        uji.append(a)
    return uji

with open('DataUjiBaru.csv','wb') as dub:
        testing = csv.writer(dub)
        datatest = d.datauji()
        datatest.pop(0)
        for x in datatest:
            testing.writerow(x)
```

I want to pair the value in self.fiturs, In self.fiturs:

```
F37,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,2,1,0,0,0,1
F10,8,4,3,3,3,6,8,5,8,4,8,4,5,6,4
F8,1,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0
```

So i want to pair index[0] and index[-5:] and write it to the csv, and the output on the csv like this:

```
F37,"['1', '0', '0', '0', '1']"
F10,"['8', '4', '5', '6', '4']"
F8,"['0', '0', '2', '0', '0']"
```

My Expectation in that csv is like this:

```
F37,1,0,0,0,1
F10,8,4,5,6,4
F8,0,0,2,0,0
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were correct about the issue with your code, it is found in the line:

```
a = [x[0],x[-5:]]
```

This creates nested items that look like this:

```
['F37', ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1']]
```

Here are two ways to fix this:

***Option 1*** - Use the `splat*` operator:

```
a = [x[0],*x[-5:]]
```

***Option 2*** - Concatenate two slices of your list:

```
a = x[:1] + x[-5:]
```

Both of these will remove the nesting of your lists, and instead give you lines looking like:

```
['F37', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1']
```

Which you can then write to your output file.